# How can I load data in same order as CSV on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to load data in the same row order as in the original input CSV file? These files are not sorted in any particular order or by any particular column.
Looks like as BigQuery loading is distributed, the order is not predictible, however tends to group nulls first.

Comment: what is the reason for this? maybe (most likely) solution somewhere else  - not in preserving order from csv?

Comment: Mikhail, I need to deliver aggregated output in the same order as input.

Comment: i think @matt_black gave you good idea - you need to have something in your input that defines that order so than you will use it to sort your output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to achieve this given the way BigQuery works behind the scenes would be to add an extra column to the csv that defines the desired order. BigQuery shuffles data around behind the scenes to optimise storage and query speed so relying on any order is impossible.

But sorting is easy, so if your dataset contains the equivalent of a rownumber, you can always recover any ordering of rows with a simple sort.

Comment: Thanks @matt_black, actually I ended doing so, not that difficult, thanks for the insight, it did the trick. I would like having this feature out of the box when ingesting, a "preserve order" checkbox would be awesome.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible. Moreover - once data is loaded into BigQuery table, and doesn't preserve static order, as BigQuery may reshuffle rows in order to optimize storage and future query performance.
Result rows of any SELECT query without outermost ORDER BY may come in different order on different invocations.