# Bigquery not retaining seqence of data (csv upload through python)

Tags: google-bigquery

The table that I was uploading had a lot of null columns and it shifted the rows with null column to the top rows and the rows with filled data to the bottom. See the null columns at the top:
[image]

What should I do to retain the sequence of data. The csv has the data in sequence CSV data:
[image]

Note 1: Saving it one by one is not an option as I have a huge data.
Note 2: I was able to save the data in sequence when I had a table with all the columns filled.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908537/how-can-i-load-data-in-same-order-as-csv-on-bigquery

Comment: I think I don't have a control over how the data is stored. BigQuery tries to reduce the data as much as it can.

Comment: But I still think adding a default value to all the columns will make sure they don't end in random order.

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant. It's not important for the data to be ordered. I was just curious if it was possible to do something like that. Moreover, the other table was storing data in order so initially I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the help guys.