# Ordering of records in BigQuery tables while running DataProc jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataproc

Ordering of records in BigQuery tables while running DataProc jobs.

While executing a Dataproc job on BigQuery tables, the order of output is changed. Even when you import a given file as a BigQuery table, the ordering of records is changed in BigQuery table.

While executing a Dataproc job on BigQuery tables, the order of output is changed. Even when you import a given file as a BigQuery table, the ordering of records is changed in BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

The order of records when importing a file in [BigQuery is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908537/how-can-i-load-data-in-same-order-as-csv-on-bigquery).

As long as the underlying table data does not change setting [maxParallelism](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#properties) to 1 will generally provide deterministic ordering (but not necessarily the order from the imported file) (over a small time frame) but is not recommended because it means the Spark application will process all data as one task which leads to scalability problems (and will be slower then using Spark's native parallelism), and it is also generally not guaranteed.

Generally, if you need data ordered in some way explicitly sorting it through the Spark API is required.